# Solving this recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

please tell me a way to solve this recurrence $$n\cdot R_n=C_1\cdot R_{n-1}+C_2\cdot R_{n-2}.$$ $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants.. There is an $n$ there in the left hand side.. it makes mess. I tried generating functions too.. But the issue is the last $n\cdot R_n$ can be written as $\frac{d}{dz}$ of $A(z)$ (generating function).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Based on your legion of followup questions, it sounds like you meant to add the condition that $C_1 \cdot C_2 \ne C_2 \cdot C_1$ and that $C_i \cdot R_j \ne R_j \cdot C_i$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(n+2)R_{n+2}x^n=\frac{1}{x^2}\left(\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}nR_nx^n-R_1x\right)=\frac{xR'(x)-R_1x}{x^2}$$
where
$$R(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}R_nx^n$$

Comment: Would you explain bit more...What is the next step? Thanks . .I have elaborated question like this /////////////////  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866960/how-to-solve-this-recurrence-relation-varying-coefficient  please click

Comment: The next step would be to solve for R(x) by solving the differential equation
$$\frac{xR'(x)- R_{1}x}{x^2}= c_{1}\frac{R(x)- R_0}{x} + c_{2}R(x)$$

Then extract the coefficient of x^n and you get the answer.

Comment: Sir,Thanks..It solves for normal case.. In my case $R(n)$ is $3\times 3$ matrix. Do I need to bother it..Shall I do normal solving method as for normal case). I have explained the issue in this link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866960/how-to-solve-this-recurrence-relation-varying-coefficient

Comment: And there are so many methods to solve this Differential equation which one will you suggest if the we have $R_n$ as $3 \times 3 $ matrix..?

Comment: I am terribly sorry about this, but if $R_n$ were a matrix, it goes beyond my abilities to find a solution. I can, sadly, only help till here.