# Solving ODE with matrices

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, derivatives, finite-differences

I have an equation  in  ODE $M{'}(x)= M(x)*A(x)$. Issue here is $A(x) =  C_1+C_2* x  $ where $C_1,C_2  $ has dimension  $3 \times 3$. And x is a scalar variable

Doubt

What is M(x)? Can any one give me the solution. Issue is matrix is involved

Comment: This question, along with your earlier [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868862), are both coming out of issues from your question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867912). It would probably be more useful if you incorporated these issues into that second link rather than separating them like this.

Comment: @Rejoy Rejoy: You'll also get more traction on this site in the long run if you follow up on previous questions -- where effort has been made to provide you with an answer

Comment: Sure ..I am a new user.. I will take care of that.. I posted it as new to avoid confusion regarding already answered  question..Thanks to both

Answer (score 0):

$M(x)=e^{\int A(x)}=ke^{C_1x+\frac{1}{2}C_2x^2}$

where $k$ is found via boundary conditions. See [matrix exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential).

Comment: Will we get  $M(x)*A(x)$ if I do  $ \frac{\mathrm{d} \{ M(x)\} }{\mathrm{d} x}$ with your M(x)? I think no because of the following hint $e^X = \sum_{k=0}^\infty{1 \over k!}X^k.$ and   $\frac{d}{dx} \exp{(x A)}=\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k \frac{x^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty A^k \frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} = A\cdot \exp(x A)$, where A is a constant $3 \times 3 $ matrix