# Quaternion conversion

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, algorithms, dynamical-systems

We have a normalized orthogonal co-ordinate frame travelling through the curve as in figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jYiv.gif) below, from one end to other. Let us call starting end as A and ending end as B. What we know is initial frame  $\psi(0)$,length of the curve L,a parameter $s \in[0,L]$ for length($s=0$ for A and $s = L$ for B,mentioned in the second picture)

[image]

**Given Data in the question**

1. Each co_ordinate  axis at each $s$ is represented by $d_i(s)=\left(\begin{array}{c}d_{ix}(s)\\ d_{iy}(s)\\ d_{iz}(s)\end{array}\right)$ and all together in frame represented by $d(s)=(d_3(s),d_2(s),d_1(s))$
2. We have a starting Co-ordinate frame say $\psi(0)$. It is a $3\times 3$ matrix and each entries are defines   by  $\psi(0) = \begin{bmatrix} d_{3x}(0)& d_{2x}( 0)&d_{1x}( 0)\\d_{3y}( 0)& d_{2y}(0)&d_{1y}(0)\\d_{3z}(0)& d_{2z}(0)&d_{1z}(0)\end{bmatrix} \tag 2 $ where $d_3$ is the tangent
3. $\psi(s) = \begin{bmatrix} d_{3x}(s)& d_{2x}( s)&d_{1x}( s)\\d_{3y}( s)& d_{2y}(s)&d_{1y}(s)\\d_{3z}(s)& d_{2z}(s)&d_{1z}(s)\end{bmatrix} \tag 3$
4. $\chi_1 = \left(\begin{array}{c}\alpha_0\\\beta_0  \\  \gamma_0\end{array}\right)\tag 4$$\chi_2 = \left(\begin{array}{c}\alpha_1\\\beta_1  \\  \gamma_1\end{array}\right)\tag 5$
   $\chi(s)=(1-\frac{s}{L})\chi_1+\frac{s}{L}\chi_2 \tag 6$, where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are twist , bend coefficients(2nos) respectively, in other words curvature vectors. It is constant for A and B, but in between these two points we interpolate it as in above eqaution (6)
5. $\psi^{'}(s)=[\chi(s)]_{\times}\psi(s)\tag 7$
6. $[\hspace{.2cm} ]_{\times}$ is defined as follows if $Y= \left(\begin{array}{c}a_0\\ b_0\\ c_0\end{array}\right)$ then    $[Y ]_{\times}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 
      0 & -c_0 & b_0 \\
      c_0 & 0 & -a_0 \\
     -b_0 & a_0 & 0 \\
      \end{array} \right)$

**Question**

** Can we write   $\psi^{'}(s)=[\chi(s)]_{\times}\psi(s) $ in terms of Quaternion calculus ? Means an equation in rotations only? Or else  as second thought,can we find a rotation matrix $R(s,\chi1,\chi2)$ such that $\psi(0)R(s,\chi1,\chi2)=\psi(s)\tag 8$

Comment: This question might be suitable for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ as well, there are a lot of questions applying quaternions.

Comment: $\chi 1$ and $\chi 2$ are constant $3 \times 1$ vectors associated with A and B. $\alpha$ is the twist on tangent axis , $\beta,\gamma$ are bend curvatures on other two cross axes .. you can take it as constants. ...Thanks

Comment: $[a]_{\times} b$ seems to be the matrix representation version of the vector product $a \times b$.

Comment: Yes. It is matrix representation of cross product. I used that to make a compatible notation

Comment: If $q(s)$ and $\omega(s)$ are the quaternions correspond to $\psi(s)$ and $\chi(s)$ in the sense

$$ q(s)({\bf i},\;{\bf j}\;,{\bf k})\bar{q}(s) = 
({\bf i},\;{\bf j}\;,{\bf k}) \psi(x)
\quad\text{ and }\quad\omega(s) = \alpha(s){\bf i} + \beta(s){\bf j} + \gamma(s){\bf k}$$
then the quaternion version of the ODE $\psi'(s) = [\chi(s)]_{\times} \psi(s)$ is simply $q'(s) = \frac12 \omega(s) q(s)$.

Comment: Is it possible to solve that ODE in quaternians..Will the rule applicable as normal ODE?

Comment: When $\omega(s) = \omega_0 + \omega_1 s$ where
$\omega_0, \omega_1$ are constant purely imaginary,
I have solved that in part III of my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/871925/59379) to your previous question. Since
$$q' = \frac{\omega}{2} q \quad\implies\quad q'' + \left( \frac14 |\omega_0 + \omega_1 s|^2 - \frac12 \omega_1\right) q = 0, $$
 the imaginary part of $(\cdots)$ in RHS is constant,
solutions of RHS is linear combination of [Parabolic cylinder function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function) which are solutions for a similar ODE over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: How did you get, $q'=\frac{w}{q}$ and also conversion for double derivative. I am bit new to quaternions.. Would you type this as answers in bit elaborated form so that new comers like me can learn the techniques